# Leaving secular books open and forgetfulness

Tags: halacha, minhag, sources-mekorot, superstition

In [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/77108/leaving-sefarim-open-and-forgetfulness) the concept of leaving Sefarim open being linked to forgetfulness is discussed. Does such a principle apply to Secular books as well or is it strictly limited to Torah-books?

(*Looking for an answer based on classical Halachic sources*)

Comment: Why might you think it applies to secular books as well, that you ask about it? Please [edit] to clarify.