# Does the concept of "leaving a sefer open leads to forgetfulness" apply to Torah on a computer screen?

Tags: minhag, torah-study, superstition

<sub>(related: "[Leaving Sefarim Open and forgetfulness](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/77108/leaving-sefarim-open-and-forgetfulness)")</sub>

The **[Be'er Hetev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ba%27er_Hetev)** in [Yoreh Deah 277](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.277.1?lang=bi&p2=Ba%27er_Hetev_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.277.1&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) quotes the **Bach** who states:

> וכתב הב''ח מכאן יש ללמוד שלא ילך אדם חוץ **ויניח הספר פתוח** [...] מי שמניח ספר פתוח ויוצא **שמשכח תלמודו**
>
> From here we learn that a person gets up/ excuses himself from what he's learning, **he shouldn't leave his *sefer* open** [...] if a person does do this [ie leave his sefer open] **he will forget his learning**

What about a person who's learning Torah on their computer: would this same principle be applied?
<sub>(ie and a person should switch tabs or minimize their window if they have to step away for a moment)</sub>